# Code snippet to lock my PC

Tags: vb.net

This is a part of my project, my project basically uses a motion sensor to detect any intrusion. So one of the modules is to lock the PC on detection of an intruder. Is there a way to lock the PC using Visual Basic?

(Because most of the other modules have been programmed in Visual Basic.) I am basically looking for source code that can implement something similar to "Windows button + L".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation"
```

Comment: well the above code din't work so just used,Shell("rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation") and it worked..thanks:)

Comment: -1 a VisualBasicScript solution (WindowsScriptHost) for a modern language as VB.NET